# How do I randomly call one of three functions without using an if statement?

Tags: python, list, oop, random, function-call

I created a class "Bruch" that creates two fractions from random numbers in a given range. There are three different types of operations that are defined in three different functions, for addition (bruchplus), subtraction(bruchminus) and multiplication (bruchmulti).

The "select(self)" function randomly calls one of these.

The code works totally fine, but I am not happy with the "if" clause in select(self). It's clumsy and ugly. There must be a more pythonic way to accomplish this. (I tried to call the functions from within a list, but that will call all the three functions, even if i just return e.g. list[0]). Looking forward to your input!

```
class Bruch:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = 'BRUCHRECHNEN'
        print(self.name)
        print('')
        self.a = Fraction(rdm.randrange(1,10,2),rdm.randrange(2,10,2))
        self.b = Fraction(rdm.randrange(1,10,2),rdm.randrange(2,10,2))   

    #randomly selects + / - / x and calls the respective function      
    def select(self):
        number = rdm.randint(0,2)
        if number == 0:
            p = self.bruchplus()
        elif number == 1:
            p = self.bruchminus()
        else:
            p = self.bruchmulti()
        return p
```

Comment: It would probably make more sense to make a single method that applies some arithmetic binary operator, and then do `random.choice([operator.add, operator.sub, operator.mul])` to choose an operation to pass into it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps you could use [`random.choice()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.choice) like this:

```
fn = random.choice([self.bruchplus, self.bruchminus, self.bruchmulti])
p = fn()
```

Comment: That solved it! - I tried this before, but totally got the brackets wrong:

p = random.choice([self.bruchplus(), self.bruchminus(), self.bruchmulti()])

This was very helpful - thanks @Robᵩ !